# Not sure how to preview my generated Nuxt3 app

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I've just created a Nuxt3 in static mode but I don't want to push it to Netlify everytime to preview it.

Here is my `nuxt.config.js` (nothing changed)

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
})
```

---

Also, I don't know why but `yarn generate` is not working as you can see below, it says

> Preview is not supported for this build

[image]

Opening the `index.html` file directly is not helping because I do have a lot of errors + my API calls are not working.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to preview your statically generated content, you will still need a light server to serve the assets + handle the API requests etc.
Even host providers like Netlify/Vercel do run a small server to serve static files.

The fastest solution is probably to use [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve), you don't have to install it directly on your system (I didn't achieved to make it work myself).

You can run `npx serve .output/public` to have something working in no time and get a functional preview.

[image]

Comment: As you said a light server is needed... In my case I use `python` module with 'python3 -m http.server' command to serve static content... Another easy approach is using `Firebase Hosting` since it takes only a few seconds to deploy static content on their CDN.

Comment: @dikesh yeah, this is also a common one indeed! I don't really use Python myself but it's a good point. Regarding Firebase, few seconds + changing windows is too much work tbh, I need to check the result in 3s max usually. Especially when debugging. Otherwise, Netlify can do that super quickly too.

Comment: I was searching for this for the while, Great to have it. One Help sir, please <I Want to Integrate Authentication Bearer based Via Graphql, In short, NUXT+Login Authentication. Please help Graphql+nuxt

Comment: Please Kissu Nuxt + Graphql Authentication please

Comment: Hi @ash, this is not the place to ask such things. Create a new question.

Comment: I created the Question. Why do I ask every time in a comment generally, no one answers these types of questions randomly. And it just wastes the effort and time of writing the Question. Please help @kissu https://stackoverflow.com/q/74815149/17226535 thankyou

Comment: Do you know that you are one of my strengths? Thank you so much for being a very kind guy. And please grow your channel. You could create a difference.