# Nuxt 3 can't recognize that my app is in a sub-folder

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

From [the docs](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt-config/#workspacedir) I tried all options resembling the one I need:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  build: {
    baseURL: '/myProject',
    workspaceDir: '/myProject',
    rootDir: '/myProject'
  }
})
```

Nothing works. In `myProject/.output/public/index.html`, I still see `<script type="module" src="/_nuxt/entry.4419fff1.js" crossorigin></script>` and I'm getting 404 console error:

> GET http://127.0.0.1/_nuxt/entry.4419fff1.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
> (Not Found)

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what it is for. Can you post you project structure?

Comment: Now do you build/preview your project?

Comment: It's a new Nuxt project I created in a `myProject` sub-folder on my server. I build it through `npx nuxi generate` command which automatically creates an `.output/public` sub-folders inside my `myProject` project folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now run `yarn preview` (or anything related, check your `package.json`, `scripts` section) to see how it looks.
As also explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72103370/8816585

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I want to do. I need to build the app because it fetches data from an Apache/mySQL backend living on the same server to avoid CORS issues, therefore I have to build the app every time I need to test it (which is extremely annoying but I see no other way to work around the CORS problem)

Comment: @drake035 fix the CORS. Probably the simplest/most efficient way when dealing with a problem: solve the problem. Rather than using a workaround. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211930/8816585

Comment: I fixed my CORS issue using the answer of yours that you linked, thanks man!