# Assets path mismatch in Nuxt3 static generation

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I develop my website using Nuxt3 and deploy it following the instructions here: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/deployment#static-hosting

I successfully get `dist` and node server hosted web (running `npx serve -o dist`) also works well, But directly opening `index.html` in brower leads to a webpage rendered without any CSS and images.

I checked the generated html and found the assets path is like:

```html
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/_nuxt/entry-1f8b74a8.mjs" as="script" crossorigin>
```

while my `dist` folder looks like:

```
dist
├── _nuxt
│   ├── entry-1f8b74a8.mjs
│   ├── entry.ff9830ad.css
│   ├── index-a3c0d3be.mjs
│   ├── index-e5b9c659.mjs
│   ├── index.072137e3.css
│   ├── lcdp-c28417d3.mjs
│   ├── manifest.json
│   ├── paper-b4b64fe8.mjs
│   └── paper.6897f003.css
├── imgs
│   ├── bg1.png
│   ├── bg2.png
│   └── other images...
└── index.html
```

I guess maybe the reason is that the assets path is wrong? What is the correct way to do the static website generation using nuxt3?

Comment: You're using SSR or SSG? For SSG or anything really, you need to run a server anyway nowadays as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72103370/8816585).

Comment: Yeah, I'm using SSG... So you mean nowadays there's no way to deploy Nuxt3 as a purely static website to the static hosting, such as GitHub pages?

Comment: Github pages will run a small server for you too actually. Same goes for Netlify and Vercel (which are miles better than GH pages anyway). There is quite a ton of platforms being able to host a Nuxt3 app for free. Most of the platforms here have a free hosting cost for SSG: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/deployment#supported-hosting-providers

Comment: This is exactly the problem I met... Even though I use the GitHub page to deploy my app, it doesn't work as well (CSS and mjs files are 404).

Comment: Just don't use GH pages, it's sub-par and has nothing special to offer when compared to Netlify/Vercel.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help! I will try some other hosting servers.

Comment: Keep us updated if you face any issues.

Comment: I successfully deployed it using Vercel and it works well. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP achieved to properly deploy the app on Vercel, it's better than Github Pages on every way anyway.